# A complete local ring is finite over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if and only if it has finitely many $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$-valued points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the ring of $p$-adic integers and $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ a fixed algebraic closure of the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of $p$-adic numbers. Let $R$ be a complete Noetherian local $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra. It is not hard to see that if $R$ is a finite $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra, then the set $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(R,\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p)$ of continuous homomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebras is finite. A natural question, then, is the reverse also true?

> Let $R$ be a complete Noetherian local $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra of characteristic zero such that the set $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(R,\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p)$ is finite. Is it true that $R$ is a finite $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra?

Comment: What about the ring of formal power series $\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$? That is an infinite complete Noetherian local $\mathbb Z_p$-algebra, but the only $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$-point is $T \mapsto 0$?

Comment: @red_trumpet I think you also have $T \mapsto x$ for any $x$ with positive valuation.

Comment: @hunter You are right. If $f(T) = \sum_k a_k T^k$, for $a_k \in \mathbb Z_p$, then $|a_k| \leq 1$, so if $|x|<1$, also $|a_k x^k| \leq |x^k| \to 0$, making $a_k x^k$ a null sequence. And by ultrametric madness, the sum over every null sequence converges.... Thank you! $p$-adic analysis is still a bit foreign to me...

Comment: Is not $\mathbb Q_p$ itself, or something like $\mathbb Q_p[x]/(x^2)$, a counterexample?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I think I answered the question the OP wanted to ask, where one additionally assumes that $R$ has finite residue field. But your example is of course correct.

Comment: @user297024 Exactly, Sorry I missed the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Added: this answer is implicitly assuming that $R$ has residue field $\mathbf{F}_p$. From context, I am guessing you are thinking about Galois deformation rings where this is always satisfied. Otherwise $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is also a counter example as Torsten Schoeneberg points out. The assumption on residue field implies that $R$ is a quotient of $\mathbf{Z}_p[[X_1,\ldots,X_d]]$ for some $d$ which is what is being implicitly used below.)

The weaker statement that $R[1/p]$ is finite over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is true (so if
$R$ is flat over $\mathbf{Z}_p$ then you are fine.)

Certainly we can assume that the Noetherian ring $R[1/p]$ has only finitely many maps
to $K = \overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p$. The point is that $R[1/p]$ is a Jacobson ring (see e.g. [http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/modseminar/pdf/L04.pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/modseminar/pdf/L04.pdf)), and that any maximal ideal $P$ of $R[1/p]$ comes from a map $R[1/p] \rightarrow K$. So to show that $R[1/p]$ is finite, it suffices to show that it is Artinian. Since $R[1/p]$ is Noetherian, it suffices to show that any prime ideal is maximal. But assume that $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime. Then by the Jacobson property, $\mathfrak{p}$ is the intersection of the maximal ideals $P_i$ which contain it. But we are assuming there are only finitely many such maximal ideals,  so

$$R[1/p]/\mathfrak{p} \simeq R[1/p]/\bigcap P_i
\simeq \prod R[1/p]/P_i,$$

where the second isomorphism is the Chinese Remainder Theorem (which one can apply since the intersection is finite). Since the LHS is a domain, this clearly shows that $\mathfrak{p} = P_i$ for some $i$ and is thus maximal.

It's not true that $R$ itself has to be finite over $\mathbf{Z}_p$; if

$$R = \mathbf{Z}_p[[x]]/(px),$$

then any map from $R$ to $K$ sends $x=0$ so there is only one such point. But $R
$ surjects onto $\mathbf{F}_p[[x]]$ so $R$ is not finite over $\mathbf{Z}_p$.